# Multiple requestparam, rest philosophy and good pratice

Tags: rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have many crud operation.
User must be able to search by many field of the resource.
Some have around 10.

I could use RequestParam, but method will have a lot of parameter an habitually it's not a good pratice.

`/card?id=2&imso=trx&icco=98x&type=23&scm=988&createat=2017-02-01`

Is there another good solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here and depending on what carries what importance to you - you can approach a solution.

**Problem # 1 :** Long REST URLs at client

**Problem # 2 :** Controller methods with long & complicated signatures

**Solution 1 :**  You group your `@RequestParam` into optional & mandatory parameters and then you create a DTO only for optional parameters. Then You can have your controller method signature like `controllerMethod(@RequestParam param1 , @RequestParam param2, DTO dto)`.

Note that, you don't use `@RequestBody` before DTO.

Values for DTO will be passed in client URL itself like before and Spring MVC automatically converts it into DTO.

This solves complicated controller method signature but not long URL problem while you retain your request type to be `GET`

It is assumed that usually mandatory parameters are only a few and there is always a long list of optional fields.

**Solution 2:** You change server side to convert your `GET` request to a `POST` and start accepting a `@RequestBody` DTO. This solves both the problems but your original API changes to POST type.

As far as I know, changing a GET to POST shouldn't be a problem in most cases but vice versa is not true.